# Value of variable is not used in expression

Tags: qgis

In a text box on a layout im am trying to calculate a value:

aggregate(
layer:='Boliger',
aggregate:='sum',
expression:="SBT",
filter:=  overlay_within( layer:='OUTPUT_2dd78fe7_5abd_4e1b_9645_e9e7887fa79e',filter:=SBT> @SBT
))

Problem is with the "filter:=SBT> @SBT" - it return the value zero.
@SBT has the value 5 and if I write "filter:=SBT> 5" I get the expected value in return.

If I delete all the above code and just put in @SBT i get the value 5, so @SBT is known.

What is going on?

[image]

Comment: I have tried to_int(@SBT) but that did not change anything. I tried with another “random” available variable @Id and it works as it should - it returns a value